# Count function from 2 tables in database

Tags: sql, count

I have 2 tables like these

rental_tabel

```
id |    date       |   cust_id               |     driver_number
1     2019-01-02          1                         F 3350 NN
2     2019-04-02          2                         AX 111 Z
3     2019-05-02          3                         S 787  X
4     2019-05-02          4                         T 9090 M
5     2019-06-02          3                         P 8989 L
```

user_table

```
cust_id |   name       
1          John          
2          Doe
3          Michael
4          Leonard
5          Steve
```

How do I count customer name who's shown more than once in the rental table?

I have using count function, and I can count the id shown more than once, but I still can't get the name of customer

Here's my count query

```
SELECT COUNT(rental_table.cust_id) AS total FROM rental_table WHERE rental_table.cust_id>'1'
```

and the result is

```
| total   |
-----------
|   2     |
```

Where's I can add to get the customer name from that count function?

Comment: Use a HAVING clause for COUNT() conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY cust_id` with the following `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT u.name
  FROM rental_table r
  JOIN user_table u
    ON u.cust_id = r.cust_id
 GROUP BY cust_id
HAVING count(cust_id) > 1
```

Comment: @IkramShabri thank you, too. Btw, please consider using related DBMS tag for your SQL questions in the future.